Aligning vehicle route with expected route in GIS with GPS variability
I have a PHP project where I am working with two polylines: one representing the expected route on streets and another representing the actual route taken by a vehicle. The expected route remains constant, but the actual route varies due to GPS inaccuracies, which can cause the vehicle's path to deviate from the expected path, especially during sharp turns or due to the GPS's ping interval (e.g., every 10 seconds).
I need a method to align the actual route with the expected route when deviations are minor, but if the vehicle significantly deviates from the expected path or starts/ends the route at different points than expected, I want to retain that part of the actual route as it is.
How can I align the actual route with the expected route while accounting for small GPS inaccuracies, and ensure that significant deviations are preserved? Are there any recommended algorithms or approaches for this problem?
Below, I have illustrated the problem:


Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a problem-solving site, but this is less a problem than a "task" for which you have not yet attempted a solution. Asking for recommendations moves this into the realm of discussion, which is off-topic here in the Q&A site. While this would be appropriate to ask in [Chat], Chat has a minimum reputation requirement and a lot less traffic. Brainstorming for solutions would likely be better accomplished in a discussion-oriented forum elsewhere.

There's plenty of room for ambiguity here, especially where <now> has excess at the start/end of <expected>.
A simple vertex-to-line distance filter alignment might be a good candidate and entry point for a first approach in SQL:
SELECT
  n.<id>,
  ST_MakeLine(
    CASE WHEN frac = 0.0 OR frac = 1.0 OR dist > <threshold>
      THEN dmp.geom
      ELSE ST_LineInterpolatePoint(e.<geom>, frac)
    END
    ORDER BY
      dmp.path
  ) AS geom
FROM
  <now> AS n
  INNER JOIN
  <expected> AS e
    ON n.<id> = e.<id>
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
    ST_DumpPoints(n.<geom>) AS dmp
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
    ST_Distance(dmp.geom, e.<geom>) AS dist
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
    ST_LineLocatePoint(dmp.geom, e.<geom>) AS frac
GROUP BY
  n.<id>
;

We keep all vertices of <new> that are either

above a distance <threshold> away from <expected> (define according to your significance) or
have their closest projected (located) point on or in excess of the start/end of the respective <expected>

or otherwise align with <expected>.
I use LATERAL joins here for comprehensive set expansion logic and iterative operations, but the whole query could also get more compressed (or further flattened).
